# Is "live" an action verb or a state verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence

I've always thought of "live" as a state verb since it implies a state rather than an action. A testament to this is the fact that we cannot use the structure "past time reference + would + live" to talk about a habitual activity in the past (e.g. in "Every summer, we would live in our villa in the country"), instead, we have to use "used to", as in "We used to live in London, but then we moved to Italy."

However, as shown in the picture, the book "Longman Academic Writing" refers to "live" as an action verb (I'm not so sure about "lose" either). I was wondering if the book has made a mistake? Or am I the one in the wrong?

[image]

Comment: What about "Every summer we would live out of suitcases"? I think that the problem with your example is that you don't really live in a place if you are only planning to spend a season there at a time.

Comment: The verb "live" in your example means "reside", and hence is dynamic not stative.

Comment: There's a lot of idioms with the verb "live", I'd be unsurprised if some were dynamic and others were stative.

Comment: 'Live a little.'

Comment: @StuartF True, but I think the question is about the sense used in the example, and idioms in general create exceptions to rules.